# Integer can be primitive, but assertTrue becomes ambiguous - how to satisfy both requirements?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, casting, integer, int

I have a simple piece of code, testing Spring repository:

```java
//repository is declared in code, doesn't really matter

@Test
public void objectTest() {
    Integer testId = 10;
    TestedObject testObj = repository.getTestedObject(testId);
    assertNotNull(testObj);
    assertEquals(testId, testObj.getId()); //testObj.getId() is an Integer, not int
}
```

This code **gives me a warning about `testId`, which can be primitive**.

When I change `testId` to primitive, ambiguity error appears, as `assertEquals(testId, testObj.getId())` **can match both `assertEquals(Object, Object)` and `assertEquals(int, int)` due to Java autoboxing feature.**

I hate unfixed warnings and I'd love to get rid of them. Warning about `testId` being non-primitive **appears only in IntelliJ IDEA**, Eclipse doesn't even care.

Should I:

- cast a variable? `assertEquals((Integer) testId, testObj.getId())`
- configure the warning severity in IDEA?

Also, I would like to leave an Integer in `getId()` method of `testObj`, in case of any object-related manipulations, which cannot be done on primitives.

Comment: You could use the primitive value of the `Integer`, like `assertEquals(testId, testObj.getId().intValue());`

Comment: instead you can use assertTrue(int value == Integer value)

Comment: @BadDeveloper that hides the expected and actual values.

Comment: @AndyTurner: Actual value is always hard coded. It doest make any difference

Comment: @user1001 It does in the exception message in case of failure.

Comment: @Slaw :If any exception occurs, test case is  anyways going to fail in both  the cases. That has to be a seperate test case. It does not cause any error while using asseryEquals incase of any exception?

Comment: @user1001 I mean when using `assertEquals` the exception message will say something like "_expected X, was Y_", whereas `assertTrue` will simply say something like "_expected true, was false_". The former gives you more information.

Comment: @Slaw: In a test, expected is already known. If a test case fails then it means expected is not equal to actual. Do we still need a message to print in the console.

Comment: @user1001 The expected value _may_ be known, and such knowledge may even be typical. However, it's also possible the expected value is partially auto-generated. But forget about the expected value—using `assertTrue` also hides the _actual_ value in this case. Knowing the actual value can help tremendously when debugging a test failure.

Comment: @Slaw:Sure..got it

Comment: It's [a bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-225594), the quick fix should not produce uncompilable code.

Comment: @Slaw is right - sometimes bad output could be caused even by mistyped code. Such value would provide information, which element generated wrong output. In my opinion, true/false should be used only when we expect binary value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: **that's a bug.** Thanks to [@Bas Leijdekkers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58556672/integer-can-be-primitive-but-asserttrue-becomes-ambiguous-how-to-satisfy-both#comment103436230_58556672) for creating bug report on JetBrains. (link [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-225594), copied from comments).

After all, I've used [@deHaar's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58556672/integer-can-be-primitive-but-asserttrue-becomes-ambiguous-how-to-satisfy-both#comment103432627_58556672) and chose the `intValue()` method.